# Incluir um botão de pesquisa dentro de uma célula d gridview c#

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

estou com o seguinte problema:

Tenho uma gridView em um sistema Windows form que estou desenvolvendo com c#. Esta grid irá servir para o usuário incluir itens de uma cotação. Na célula produto, aonde o usuário digita o código do produto, eu gostaria que aparecesse um botão assim que a célula ficasse pronta para edição, ou seja, assim que permitisse o usuário digitar. Este botão, aparecendo bem no cantinho da célula servirá para o usuário pesquisar os produtos existentes.

É possível fazer isso ? Pesquisei na net mas não encontrei nada parecido.

Obrigado....

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que entendi você quer criar um ComboBox na grid. O código abaixo resolve:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
cmb.HeaderText = "Selecione um produto";
cmb.Name = "cmb";
cmb.Items.Add("Arroza");
cmb.Items.Add("Feijão");
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(cmb);
```

Comment: Na verdade não, estou querendo criar um botão mesmo. É um botão Elipse, que chama. Um exemplo deste botão é na propriedades da Grid, quando vc clica na opção ColumnHeadersDefaultCell...Daí, ele permite vc digitar ou clicar no botão com os três "pontos" ... e após clicar neste botão ele abre uma janela...Eu queria fazer isso em meu grid.

Comment: eu posso encontrar uma solução assim pra você. Mas você vai ter que implementar uma janela pra pesquisar os itens dessa forma...